# AND-like comparison of array members in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, comparison

I have a situation where I create multiple arrays from conditions imposed on data which I need to compare.

For instance consider this set of data (in cells):

```
A1: ASD
A2: ASF
A3: 
A4: NOTTHISONE
```

I then impose two conditions:

```
NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A4) and;
LEN(A1:A4)<4
```

which return the following respective arrays

```
{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE} and;
{TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}
```

I then wish to make an AND comparison on the VALUES of these arrays (not comparing the full arrays). This should yield:

```
{TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE}
```

But using AND() or '=' appears to compare the two arrays as full objects and hence returns false (as {TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}!={TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE}).

Is there a way to achieve the comparison I am looking for?

Comment: So as an output, what are you trying to get? `True, True, False, False`? As you noted, `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A4)),LEN(A1:A4)<4)` will evaluate to just `False`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel (and quite a few programming languages), 'True' can also be represented as '1', and likewise, 'False' by '0'.

Additionally, 'AND' is equivalent to multiplication, and 'OR' to addition (you can look into bitwise operations AND and OR if you want to).

With these two in mind, you can use multiplication to get an array out of the two formulae you have:

```
=NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A4))*(LEN(A1:A4)<4)
```

Now, the above won't exactly give you an array of true and false, not as it is anyway, because excel sees that the formula's result will go into a cell, and a cell cannot contain an array.

If you put the same in a formula that can take and use an array however...

```
=INDEX(NOT(ISBLANK(A1:A4))*(LEN(A1:A4)<4),0,0)
```

[image]

And here the first sentence I mentioned applies. You can see the result is `{1;1;0;0}`, in other words, True, true, false, false.

Comment: Perfect, this is just what I need. Thank you.